# Change all characters in a string to unicode applied to whole column pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I have a string:

```
fruit1 = 'apple'
```

and to change it to unicode code point:

```
fruit 1 = int(''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in fruit1))
print(fruit1)

97112112108101
```

Is it possible apply the same concept over a whole column without running a for loop on every value?

```
Sample Table:

 | Fruit |
  ------- 
 | apple |
 | berry |
 | kiwi  |
```

Desired output:

```
| Number         |
 ----------------
| 97112112108101 |
| 98101114114121 |
| 107105119105   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `map` and `apply` are loops under the hood, but working here:

```
df['new'] = df['Fruit'].map(lambda x:  int(''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in x)))
#alternative
#df['new'] = df['Fruit'].apply(lambda x:  int(''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in x)))
print (df)
   Fruit             new
0  apple  97112112108101
1  berry  98101114114121
2   kiwi    107105119105
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the reason you need that (?!), yes, it is possible:

```
df['Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].apply(lambda fruit1: int(''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in fruit1)))
```